# How to do "pull" command using Pygithub API

Tags: github, pull, pygithub

I'm not familiar with Pygithub API, I have done the "clone" action, but I don't know how to "pull" to update repositories that already cloned.

I have "clone" repositories from github

```
client = Github(base_url=f'https://{hostname}/api/v3', login_or_token=token)
repos = client.get_organization(organization).get_repos()

for repo in repos:
   Repo.clone_from(remote, local)
```

Comment: Hi, I think you should use ** gitpython** to achieve it. pygithub has more api about execution in the "Github website" but your wants to do sth about "git".    Their diff is like docker & dockerhub.